# Problema al adjuntar un archivo via SOAP para un WSDL (MTOM)

Tags: c#, webservice, soap, soapui

He creado un servicio web y he añadido mi función bastante simple, obteniendo como parámetro un campo de tipo `Stream`.

Tras eso he tratado de testar desde el SoapUI. Cuando esta sin activar el MTOM todo va correcto, el problema surge al exigirlo.

> HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";
>   start=""; start-info="text/xml";
>   boundary="----=_Part_133_2094112.1548776402204"' was not the expected
>   type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.

He conseguido solucionarlo despues de bastantes horas y creo que puede ser útil para la comunidad, así que lo cuelgo paso por paso en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que la parte de crear un proyecto etc ya la conocemos todos, de todas formas lo resumo.

He creado un proyecto `WCF` y dentro de el un servicio `SVC`.

---

**CREAR EL SERVICIO**

---

Lo primero que he hecho es añadir mi función al fichero `svc`

```
public int Upload(Stream data)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Una función simple que recibe un `Stream` cómo parámetro y devuelve `int` como respuesta (la intención de `int` es controlar códigos de error para notificar a los clientes que la llamen).

Tras terminar con mi función la he nombrado en la interfaz.

```
[OperationContract]
int Upload(Stream data);
```

---

**WEB.CONFIG**

---

Esta parte es la que mas problemas me da, olvidaos de lo que genera por defecto, el mapeo del binding etc. Os recomiendo copiar directamente este código y luego meter tema de seguridad etc despues de haber testado que funciona todo correctamente:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" messageEncoding="Mtom">
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="ServicioWCF.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="ServicioWCF.IService1">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Es importante nombrar bien al `binding` y llamarla adecuadamente en todos los lugares, en mi caso es "basicHttp".

El nombre del `servicio` y el `contract` debe ser el mismo que el proyecto. Si no no va a funcionar.

El tipo de binding yo he colocado `basicHttpBinding` pero obviamente dependerá del tipo de proyecto que tengas.

Por último es muy importante que no nos olvidemos de codificar el binding: `messageEncoding="Mtom"`.

---

**SoapUI**

---

Lo mismo, entiendo que conocemos como probar servicios en el programa, de todas maneras en la misma web esta bastante bien indicado.

Algo que si me gustaría indicar es que el `ID` debe de ser el mismo que el número `cid` y no el que genera automáticamente el programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Activamos `MTOM` en las propiedades que aparecen debajo a la izquierda. Yo he puesto que fuerce su uso también.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto debería de funcionar la comunicación sin ningún problema, si depuramos podemos ver que el `stream` llega correctamente y en SoapUI vemos que el `WSDL` esta devolviendo un "1".

---

**STREAM A FICHERO**

---

El `Stream` no es un `Stream` cualquiera, viene dado como `bodyStream` por lo que su transformación en fichero directamente es imposible. (si alguien sabe hacerlo que comente porfa).

En mi caso he resuelto esta parte pasándolo a `Memory stream` y de eso a un `FileStream` (directamente no me convierte). Guardo el `Filestream` en la ruta deseada y vuala!

---

**APORTACIONES**

---

Espero que os sirva y cualquier aportación bienvenida sea, yo tampoco conozco bien el tema, pero he perdido muchas horas buscando una solución que espero que ahorre tiempo a otra gente ;P

---